# Digi XBEE RF 900 modem

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having an issue trying to do an insert into mysql from Digi HP900 RF modem. I can grad the data from the device but it won't read the data correctly to do the insert. Does anyone see any issues with this syntax here :

```
    import mysql.connector;
    from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
    
    # TODO: Replace with the seri

al port where your local module is connected to.
PORT = "/dev/ttyUSB1"
# TODO: Replace with the baud rate of your local module.
BAUD_RATE = 115200


def main():
print(" +
+")
print(" | XBee Python Library Receive Data Sample |")
print(" +
+\n")

device = XBeeDevice(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

try:
device.open()

def data_receive_callback(xbee_message):
print("From %s >> %s" % (xbee_message.remote_device.get_64bit_addr(),
xbee_message.data.decode()))

device.add_data_received_callback(data_receive_callback)
xbee_message = device.read_data()
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',database='dbcapture',user='root',password='XXXX')
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("insert INTO dbtable (`post_id`, `tempdata`, `split0`, `status`, `lastupdate`, `text`, `content`, `likes`) VALUES ('1', %s, 'split0', '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'mynkey', 'joe', 'hello'),(xbee_message);")
connection.commit()
connection.close()
print("Success")
input()
print("Waiting for data...\n")

finally:
if device is not None and device.is_open():
device.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Is this Python?

Comment: yes it is python

Comment: Your error is probably in the `cur.execute` line. You've closed the string *after* putting the `xbee_message` field. Also, what is the format of the `xbee_message` variable? Do you have an example of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through [documentation for the MySQLCursor.execute()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) method, I think you need to fix your execute call.  Move `(xbee_message)` out of the INSERT string passed as the operation, and into the second parameter for the data.  I also removed some quoting which seemed unnecessary.

```
cur.execute("insert INTO dbtable "
            "(post_id, tempdata, split0, status, lastupdate, text, content, likes) "
            "VALUES (1, %s, 'split0', 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'mynkey', 'joe', 'hello')", 
            (xbee_message))
```

Comment: Perfect, you were right and this is solved